# SSRS Parameter Date Format

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I’m having some issues with SSRS reports parameter date formatting. I have a system that uses the WinForms report viewer in a VB.net system. The server where the reports are processed uses format `MM/dd/yyyy` and the system uses `dd/MM/yyyy`. I can’t change this or the system as both are required to have those settings.

The issue is that although the calendars are showing the date as `dd/MM/yyyy` and entering it into the parameter fields in that format the date is still being parsed as `MM/dd/yyyy`.

If the date is entered as `MM/dd/yyyy` after the dates are parsed they are switched back to displaying in `dd/MM/yyyy` which then either fails to parse or parses backward if the user attempts to run the report again. 
The reports are standard SSRS 2005 reports using SQL Server 2005 stored procedures.

I’ve set the `Language` property of the report to `=User!Language` and while this has caused the calendars to set the date in the correct format the parse is still not working correctly.

I’m using version 8.0.0.0 of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms and .Net 3.5. I can upgrade one or both if need be. The system is running on Windows 7 64 bit.

The regional settings for my computer are set to `dd/MM/yyyy`

As requested I'm adding the .net report code.

This issue affects all reports that have a DateTime parameter.

Date parameters are entered into the list as shown. CustomCalendarControl is a MaskedTextBox with some styling. Format is `dd/MM/yyyy`

```
paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("start", datCustomCalendarControl.Text, False))
```

The code below runs the report. The method accepts  bv_strReportName and a optional List(of ReportParameter). If no parameters are passed the control will prompt the user for the parameters. The issue affects parameters that are passed in via the bv_ParameterList and parameters that are entered through the control. reportViewer is a standard WinForms ReportViewer control.

```
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = Globals.ReportServerLocation
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = Globals.ReportPathLocation & bv_strReportName
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("USER", "PASSWORD")

if (bv_ParameterList IsNot Nothing) Then
    reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(bv_ParameterList)
    reportViewer.RefreshReport()
End If
```

Any help you could offer would be appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I've updated my question to include some of the .net code as per your suggestion. Comment or pm if you have any other suggestions

Comment: Similar questions have been asked a lot of times. Dates have no format. Format applies only when they are converted to strings. If your report parameters, query, stored procedure parameters and date fields *are* actually date typed, you shouldn't have any problems. Obviously, you are converting dates to strings at some point. The real solution is to convert them to date types.

Comment: In short, *don't*  pass `datCustomCalendarControl.Text` as a parameter. Change the `start` report parameter to a date type, use a control that returns a date or use DateTime.Parse/ParseExact to convert the text to a DateTime. You could also change the mask to allow dates in the unambiguous format 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Comment: ReportParameter only accepts a String so how can I change it to a date? I could add a property to the control to return the date as a `yyyy-MM-dd` formatted String or I could add a pre-process step to convert to that format in the constructor but that would only fix my issue when the parameters are known before the report is run. The parameters from the ReportViewer control have the same issue and there is no event that I can listen for to pre-process parameters before they're sent to the server. The simplest would be to change the mask but the users want the format they have